# golang upload file err runtime error index out of range

Tags: file-upload, go, runtime-error

I've put together a golang func that takes an uploaded file and saves it to folder. 
Just before `os.Create()` I am getting the following error :

`http: panic serving [::1]:64373: runtime error: index out of range`

My golang function is:

```
func webUploadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

 file, header, err := r.FormFile("file") // the FormFile function takes in the POST input id file

 if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
    return
 }
 defer file.Close()

 // My error comes here

 messageId := r.URL.Query()["id"][0]
 out, err := os.Create("./upload/" + messageId + ".mp3")

 if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Unable to create the file for writing. Check your write access privilege")
    return
 }
 defer out.Close()

 // write the content from POST to the file
 _, err = io.Copy(out, file)
 if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
 }

 fmt.Fprintf(w,"File uploaded successfully : ")
 fmt.Fprintf(w, header.Filename)

}
```

any ideas? much appreciate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should at least check if  `r.URL.Query()["id"]` has actually one element.

If `len(r.URL.Query()["id"])`, you could consider not accessing the index 0.

Easier, [Ainar-G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1892060/ainar-g) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804092/golang-upload-file-err-runtime-error-index-out-of-range/25804169?noredirect=1#comment40362864_25804169) to use the [Get() method](http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values.Get)

> Get gets the first value associated with the given key.
>   **If there are no values associated with the key, Get returns the empty string**.
>   To access multiple values, use the map directly.

Comment: @bboy that explains the out of index error message, and you need to adapt your code to process that case.

Comment: @bboy I have edited the answer: you can also use Get, and process the case where the returned value for "id" is an empty string. Same issue. As for the lack of "id", I suspect your URL isn't properly formed, and the attribute is not recognized.